# Копр и укроп этимология

Tags: этимология

Обратил внимание на странную миграцию располагавшейся ранее на конце ст.-слав. слова "коп**р**" буквы Р. , однако затем переместившейся в русском языке чуть ли не в начало корня "ук**р**оп".

Является ли данный случай с буквой Р. единичным либо же это какое-то систематическое явление?

Comment: Не «ст.слав.», а старослав. (старославянский). Не «буква "р"», а буква Р.

Comment: Не «буква "Р"», а буква Р.